# Ubuntu 12.04 won't mount Samsung SE-218BB

Tags: 12.04, drivers, usb-drive, dvd, samsung

I can't seem to mount the drive even though Samsung advertises it as being Linux compatible when switching it over to AV mode (by ejecting the tray and holding the eject button until the LED comes on) I have tried inserting a cd into the drive but it acts as if it is going to start reading the disk and then suddenly stops spinning after about 1 second and repeats this process. I checked the Disk Utility app and the drive will show up along with the other devices like the hard drive for only a second or two and then disappear and repeat this as well. I have tested two different SE-218BBs and both have this same strange behavior. All of my other usb devices work fine when plugged in. The standard mode was read without any problems when I booted Windows 7.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 on a Toshiba Satellite C655D. Thanks for any help.